Is there a way to get unique identifier for a desktop app which is same for cross OS's?
Is there a way to get a unique identifier for an application on a computer that is consistent across operating systems? Or maybe even linkable to a web domain?
I'll give an example - let's say I'm developing a desktop application X.
Application X has an access to many windows on the computer.
I would like it to know for each window (application) what its unique identifier, so I can provide specific settings for this application.
For instance, my Application X is opened, and the user is working on Slack for example, and also maybe he named the application on their computer "My Slack".
I would like my application X to receive some kind of identifier for that application, that will always return "slack" on both Windows and Mac.
If it could even be linked to their web domain, that would be amazing, for example 'slack.com,'
Does anyone know if something like that is possible?
I couldn't find anything online.
